# Why am I not getting the correct number of objects in my list?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function to generate a list of tuples. I have this:

```
import random

def generate_list(count):
    l_names = ['scott', 'anderson', 'philips', 'peterson', 'parker']
    f_names = ['james', 'chris', 'lisa', 'mary', 'kate']
    names = []
    counter = 0

    for name in f_names:
        counter += 1
        my_tuple = (counter, f_names[random.randint(0, len(f_names)-1)], \
            l_names[random.randint(0, len(l_names)-1)])
        names.append(my_tuple) 
    return my_tuple

people = generate_list(3)
print(f"People list: {people}")
```

When I use generate_list(3), I want three tuples in my list. But I'm only getting one. I feel like the mistake is somewhere in the for loop and its return statement. But I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: `return names` instead of `return my_tuple`?

Comment: You are not using `count`

Comment: Use `random.choice(f_names)` instead of `f_names[random.randint(0, len(f_names)-1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `for name in f_names` to `for name in range(count)` and `return mytuple` to `return names`, since you are returning one tuple not the list of names.

```
import random

def generate_list(count):
    l_names = ['scott', 'anderson', 'philips', 'peterson', 'parker']
    f_names = ['james', 'chris', 'lisa', 'mary', 'kate']
    names = []
    counter = 0

    for name in range(count):  #change f_names to count
        counter += 1
        my_tuple = (counter, random.choice(f_names), \
            random.choice(l_names))
        names.append(my_tuple) 
    return names #return names not my_tuples

people = generate_list(3)
print(f"People list: {people}")
```

Comment: Ah! The range(count) is how I pass that limit to the function! I tried changing my counter to count and that was a nope. I tried returning names and then I ended up getting the whole list back. Man, being a newbie is rough. :) Thank you, Jonas! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def generate_list(count):
    l_names = ['scott', 'anderson', 'philips', 'peterson', 'parker']
    f_names = ['james', 'chris', 'lisa', 'mary', 'kate']
    names = []
    counter = 0

    while counter < count:
        counter += 1
        my_tuple = (counter, f_names[random.randint(0, len(f_names)-1)], \
            l_names[random.randint(0, len(l_names)-1)])
        names.append(my_tuple)
    return names

people = generate_list(3)
print(f"People list: {people}")
```

The idea was correct however the for loop you created went on through all of the names of `f_names` which wasn't the thing you were looking for. So you can change the for loop to a simple while loop so it will stop when it reached the count which was given in the function.

Comment: Hi Jordy, that works well also. I knew I had to do something with the count but couldn't sort out where to do it. Thanks for your help and for taking the time to write the explanation. Much appreciated.